# function call another function in Module.Exports Node.JS

Tags: node.js, module

I'm trying to make a function call inside my module but I'm getting `functionTwo` is not define.

`Module.js`

```
// Module.exports
module.exports = function ( arg ) {

if(arg instanceof Object) {

    return functionTwo.apply(arg);
}

 functionOne: function(arg) {}

 functionTwo: function(arg) { //in here we may call functionOne or functionThree }

 functionThree: function() {}
```

`Main.js`

```
require(module)(typeObject);
require(module)(typeString);
```

So basically what I'm trying to do is if the type that is being passed from `main.js` to the `module.js` was an `Object` I want it to call a specific function and do something then just return, but I don't know maybe I'm defining the function wrong.

Comment: Your snippet is invalid JS. Can you please post real code? Mostly, what object are `functionOne` and such part of?

Comment: @loganfsmyth it's the module from here https://github.com/mozilla/node-webmaker-loginapi/blob/master/index.js.

I want to create something like if the `app.get( "/user/:userid", function( req, res ) {` get fired will call one of the function inside the module.

Comment: @loganfsmyth say when I do the `require` from the `main.js` and if the url that is entered `localhost:3000/user/:userid` will call some function in the module, but I can't figure out why I can do that.